# What exactly is "Bodily Harm" and (how) does it differ from actual bodily harm?

Tags: criminal-law, definition

I'm trying to understand the following statement (which is section 53 of the [Crimes Act 1961](http://www.legislation.govt.nz/act/public/1961/0043/latest/whole.html#DLM327394) in New Zealand, bolding mine) -

> "Every one in peaceable possession of any movable thing under a claim
>   of right, and every one acting under his or her authority, is
>   protected from criminal responsibility for defending his or her
>   possession by the **use of reasonable force**, even against a person
>   entitled by law to possession, if he or she does not strike or do
>   **bodily harm** to the other person."

FWIW, the only relevant information in the Interpretation section of the act states -

> "to injure means to cause actual bodily harm"

I realise I don't understand the exact meaning of bodily harm.

A (fictitious) scenario - I'm reading a book I bought with money from a joint account and another owner of the account attempts to snatch book from me.  **If I prevent this accidentally scratch that person while so doing, have I caused them bodily harm?**

Is it relevant if I just grazed the skin or if there is a line of blood?  What if I did not actually cause visible damage but caused pain which lasted a short while?

The problem I have here is the juxtaposition of "reasonable force" and "bodily harm"

Thinking on this further, what is the difference between bodily harm and grivious bodily harm?

Comment: Maybe change the example to the other person is trying to take the book and in blocking him you graze or inadvertently elbow him. A plain reading says that the person in possession can defend, so in your current scenario once the other person snatched the book then he is in possession and has a right to defend against you. (IANAL and not from NZ).